# Visual Studio 2010 Express hangs for a few minutes when I start and stop debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a project I have been working on for a while - it is now relatively large/complex. That being said, it still always compiled and ran in the debugger very quickly (5-10 seconds from build to load).

All of a sudden though, it now takes ~2 mins to 'Start Debugging', and a similar time to Stop Debugging when the application is closed.

I'm almost certain this is not down to any code changes, and it also does not happen with any of my other projects.

When deployed/installed, the application starts very quickly, which again makes me think it is not a code issue. Additionally, VS is still very fast at Building or Publishing the project.

What could be the cause?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you're loading debug symbols at startup from a remote symbol server. Check Tools -> Options -> Debugging.

Comment: Does it do it on a different computer, a different version of VS Express, or on a previously fast rev of your code?

Comment: @CodyGray I checked, and no it doesn't seem I am.

Comment: @Austin I'm not easily able to test on a different computer or a different version of VS, but I can confirm that older revisions don't suffer from the problem

Comment: Like, since the problem started happening you went back to Rev X in a repository and it is fine or you tested it last week and it was fine?  VS Express 2012 and 2013 are both free, might be an easy test?  It takes like 10 minutes to install (did it today, actually): http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787

Comment: @Austin I make regular backups of the project - loading any which are dated before the issue started are ok. However, I haven't made any changes to the startup/cleanup code so don't understand what would be causing the hang at these times. Especially as it doesn't happen when deployed/installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to fix this by replacing the `.csproj` file with an older version I had saved from before the problem occurred.

I have not compared the contents yet to see exactly what caused this, but I will update this answer if I do.